# How to get quote object through customer id in magento2?

Tags: magento2, quote

When customer login through customer id i have to get quote object.
In magento i have written this code.but in magento2 how to get quote collection.or quote id of that customer.

```
$quoteCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
                ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $store)
                ->addOrder('updated_at');
            $quote = $quoteCollection->getFirstItem();
            $quoteId = (int) $quote->getId();
```

Comment: Try with `$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote')->load($customerId);`

Answer (score 3):

First you need to create Quote Collection object

```
public function __construct(Template\Context $context,\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory, array $data = [])
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
}
```

After that you need to filter Collation by customer id

```
public function getQuoteCollection($customerId)
{
    $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId);
    return $quote;
}
```