# Add multiple products to cart using product ids

Tags: magento2, javascript, addtocart

I am trying to add multiple products to my cart. I have product ids in the form of `$productIds = implode(',', array_column($points, 'productId'));` which gives me numeric product ids like this : `5330,3770,4259,5107,6537`. I want to put all this products to cart on button click.

I have been trying this from so long with 0 luck.I tried accepted solution of this question: [Add to cart via Javascript in CE 2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176842/add-to-cart-via-javascript-in-ce-2-1)

Any help ? I am on magento 2

Comment: show us the code you've tried even if it didn'T work

Comment: @PhilippSander updated the question